# git push by sshssh: kex_exchange_identification: read: Software caused connection abort error

Tags: php, symfony, ssh, deployment

I'm facing an error which seems to have a lot of similar questions, but any of those ones don't respond my need. I'm trying to deploy a Symfony app by git command. I must use ssh to do it, by after I created my repository, I encounter this issue when I want to push my remote repository:

> kex_exchange_identification: read: Software caused connection abort
> banner exchange: Connection to my.I.P.Address port 22: Software caused connection abort
> fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
> Please make sure you have the correct access rights
> and the repository exists.

Has someone faced this?
Thanks for your help

Comment: This doesn't have anything to do with Git. It just means there's no ssh *server* on that IP address. You can observe this with `ssh <user>@<ipaddress> echo test` or similar. Once that works, Git should work.

Comment: I've my hosting from lws.fr platform. Must I conclude that lws does not offer ssh server??

Comment: Well, you should ask *them*. Perhaps it's an option.